# Multiplication in JADE

Tags: node.js, pug

It would be nice to multiply two fields inside Jade, if it is possible. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
tbody
 each item in items
  tr
   td #{item.sku}
   td.text-center #{item.price}
   td.text-center #{item.quantity}
   //td #{item.quantity} * #{item.price}
   // - var totals = {item.price} * {item.quantity};
   //td #{totals}
   td #{item.quantity} * #{item.price}
```

Tried different approaches, no one works sofar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what your looking for:

```
tbody
  each item in items
    tr
      td #{item.sku}
      td.text-center #{item.price}
      td.text-center #{item.quantity}
      td.text-right= item.quantity*item.price
      // - var totalPrice = item.quantity*item.price
      // td.text-right #{totalPrice}
      // td.text-right #{item.quantity * item.price}
      // All three of the above methods work to do what you want to do
```

There are two ways to include javascript into your jade templates, as described [here](http://jade-lang.com/reference/code/).

Comment: Perfect, but now I want to attach a dollar sign at the end of the result D:

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi, I haven't used jade in quite a while, but my guess would be something like `td.text-right #{item.quantity * item.price}$` would work, no?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I solved it yesterday with this 
td=product.price* product.quantity +'LL'
(LL was the currency I wanted to add)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a multiply function as part of your jade locals. If you're using express, you can make this available throughout your app with `app.locals` like this:

**app.js:**

```
app.locals.multiply = function(a, b) {
    return a * b;
};
```

**jade template**

```
tbody
 each item in items
  tr
   td #{item.sku}
   td.text-center #{item.price}
   td.text-center #{item.quantity}
   //td #{item.quantity} * #{item.price}
   // - var totals = {item.price} * {item.quantity};
   //td #{totals}
   td #{multiply(item.quantity, item.price)}
```

Or with jade only:

```
var helpers = {
    multiply: function(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}

var fn = jade.compile('string of jade', options);
var html = fn(_.extend(yourModel, helpers));
```

Noe that you maybe shouldn't put this much logic in your templates. Tasks such as computing totals probably belong in a model object. Doing this allows you to reuse it in other views and write unit tests against it.